# Metro apps won't start under consumer preview of Windows 8

Tags: windows-8-preview, modern-ui

I upgraded from Windows 7 Pro to Windows 8 Consumer Preview and the Metro apps won't start when clicked. The app appears to start, the screen fills up with a green background with the app logo centered, but nothing happens afterwards. After searching for a similar issue on the web, I've found a few posts regarding a similar issue in the developer preview and have already verified that my resolution is large enough - 1440x900, and that UAC is properly enabled.

The Windows Event viewer shows only one anormal event - DCOM Event ID 10010 (Service failed to register within the time provided), after the application fails to start. But I believe this is more a result of the problem I'm having and not the cause.

My install is on a Dell XPS laptop, and not inside a virtual machine.

I'm not prepared yet to do a clean install and would like to have it work with my installed apps.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the upgrade from a stable version of an operating system to what basically amounts to a beta.

Comment: Yes, i'm positive it is related to the upgrade as well, but would still like to fix it without having to do a clean install.

Comment: Posted under TechNet forums as well, getting some replies and other users with the same issue: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itprogeneral/thread/b0e4f9a3-4c96-4e6f-9399-71fc5813853c

Comment: Problem seems to be affecting a lot of users, seems either related to the ATI display driver or the upgrade from Windows 7.